# Problems WPF binding through a contained object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to use WPF binding to an object that is contained by the DataContext object and it is not working.

If I place all binding elements in the DataContext ViewModel object, everything works, but if I separate out the data list and data elements into a separate class that is contained by the ViewModel class, the ListBox data will work, but the binding to the individual data elements is not working.

With my experimentation, I assume that the bound object needs to be directly bound to the DataContext ViewModel class.  I can do that and it works, but it's not as object oriented or reusable as I would like it to be. I've separated out the data list for the ListBox into it's own class and I'm assuming that since it is an ObservableCollection it works regardless of it being attached to the contained object.  Since the individual data elements of the objects are only notified through OnPropertyChanged, no matter what I've tried, I can't get the WPF form to recognize the data, even though the DataContext.CurrentRecord shows the correct data.  I can only assume that the OnPropertyChanged notification are not going where I need them to go.

Partial Code for DataContext ViewModel is as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items
{
    get { return ItemListMgr.Items; }
    set { ItemListMgr.Items = value; }
}

public ItemModel CurrentItem
{
    get { return ItemListMgr.CurrentItem; }
    set { ItemListMgr.CurrentItem = value; }
}
```

Corresponding code in Contained ItemListMgr object is as follows:

```
public readonly ItemListModel _ItemList;
public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items
{
    get { return _ItemList.Items; }
    set
    {
        _ItemList.Items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}

private ItemModel _currentItem;
public ItemModel CurrentItem
{
    get { return _currentItem; }
    set
    {
        _currentItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
    }
}
```

The "Items" object is the list that gets displayed and even using the contained object "ItemListMgr", this part still works great.  As the user scrolls through the list CurrentItem is set to the active item in "Items", but even though the WPF data entry elements are bound to the CurrentItem elements, they will not change when I scroll through the list.

The Xaml code to bind a text box is as follows:
    Text="{Binding CurrentItem.ItemName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"

The Xaml code binds to the DataContext object, which is using a simple pass through to the contained ItemListMgr class. I've tried to add the OnPropertyChange to the pass through elements, but that didn't help and I would guess only added to the confusion.

As this is a large amount of code and fairly complex, I hope that I've given enough key elements for you to understand what I'm doing.  Hopefully there is a way to allow this type of binding as it will greatly enhance what I'm doing.

Whatever help you can give will be greatly appreciated,
Paul

Comment: Try to use OnPropertyChanged on ViewModel not only on Managers.

Comment: The `TextBox` binding by default is `LostFocus` try adding this to your binding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.